# UIC doesn't output to a file

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

It just doesn't.

I'm fairly certain this is an issue with my computer, possibly due to the path variables, because I get the same problem with qt 5.11 as well as qt 5.12. It also seems like I'm not the only one who's had this problem—see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948185/generate-h-and-cpp-from-ui-file)—which works, but it's going to be pretty painful to do this for every `*.ui` file and dump it exactly where visual studio and/or the build bat script that MuseScore comes with expects it to be.

This is an example of what I'm trying to do and a fairly annoying work around:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.471]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\ProjectFiles\mscore\MuseScore\zerberus>uic zerberus_gui.ui -o ui_zerberus_gui.h

C:\ProjectFiles\mscore\MuseScore\zerberus>ls
CMakeLists.txt  channel.h   instrument.cpp  sfz.cpp    zerberus.cpp     zerberusgui.cpp  zone.h
README          filter.cpp  instrument.h    voice.cpp  zerberus.h       zerberusgui.h
channel.cpp     filter.h    sample.h        voice.h    zerberus_gui.ui  zone.cpp

C:\ProjectFiles\mscore\MuseScore\zerberus>uic zerberus_gui.ui > ui_zerberus_gui.h

C:\ProjectFiles\mscore\MuseScore\zerberus>ls
CMakeLists.txt  channel.h   instrument.cpp  sfz.cpp            voice.h       zerberus_gui.ui  zone.cpp
README          filter.cpp  instrument.h    ui_zerberus_gui.h  zerberus.cpp  zerberusgui.cpp  zone.h
channel.cpp     filter.h    sample.h        voice.cpp          zerberus.h    zerberusgui.h
```

This is what my path variables look like:

```
C:\ProjectFiles\mscore\MuseScore\zerberus>echo %PATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Propellerhead Software\ReWire\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Propellerhead Software\ReWire\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin;C:\Qt\5.12.0\msvc2017_64\bin;C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;

C:\ProjectFiles\mscore\MuseScore\zerberus>
```

[This is the build output from when I tried to build MuseScore;](https://pastebin.com/RMHgx3Qi) output too large so posting on PasteBin.

Hopefully I can get this going before MuseScore 3.0 is released to fix a few bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I'm using an antivirus called Comodo which is usually actually quite good, but the "sandbox" feature is a little overzealous and makes things silently fail in odd ways, I usually keep it off but it somehow came on again. UIC is currently working now.